# Looping through a string inside a Mysql Procedure

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a store procedure which takes a comma separated string as parameter. For ex: id_list = '23, 45, 8, 106, 9, 33'. Inside the procedure I want to loop through the string, extract one ID from the string at a time and pull the data from the DB. Basically the ID will be used in the where condition inside the procedure.

So Ideally I should get the ID's like this

23 
45
8
106
9
33

I have tried doing this, but its only extracting the first id and then stops.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_test`(IN id_list VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE id_length    INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE id_sub_str INT DEFAULT 0;

  IF id_list IS NULL THEN
    SET id_list = '';
  END IF;

do_this:
  LOOP
    SET id_length = LENGTH(id_list);

    SELECT mechanics_name, mechanics_id from `mechanics` WHERE employer_id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_list, ',', 1);

    SET id_sub_str = CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_list, ',', 1)) + 2;
    SET id_list = MID(id_list, id_sub_str, id_length);

    IF id_list = '' THEN
      LEAVE do_this;
    END IF;
  END LOOP do_this;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Where do you want those results?In a new table?

Comment: OR use `WHERE employer_id IN(SELECT blah FROM t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on my machine

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procedurename(IN Param1 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @text := TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM Param1);
  SET @strLen := 0;
  SET @i := 1;

  WHILE @strLen < LENGTH(@text)  DO
    SET @str := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@text, ',', @i);
    SET @strLen := LENGTH(@str);
    SET @i := @i + 1;

    INSERT INTO t VALUES( SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, ',', -1)); -- Print split value
  END WHILE;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It insert the data into a table t with a single column,so you need to create it first.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(blah INT)
```

and then just call it

```
CALL procedurename('23, 45, 8, 106, 9, 33');

SELECT * FROM t

23
45
8
106
9
33
```

Comment: Instead of inserting @str in a new table can I use the value of @str as a where condition in select query. Like SELECT mechanics_name, mechanics_id from `mechanics` WHERE employer_id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, ',', -1);

Comment: @sandeep So you want IN? if so use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(employer_id,@str)>0`

Comment: Yeah, I have tested with FIND_IN_SET. But I don't know why its pulling only one record. For ex: If I am passing '23, 45, 8, 106, 9, 33', its only pulling the mechanics_name and mechanics_id of 23. Its kind of weird.

Comment: @sandeep can you recreate the issue on sqlfiddle?

Comment: Got the issue and corrected it. SET @str := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@text, ', ', @i);  Gave an space after comma. Thanks Mihai.